# SharePoint Online responds with HTTP 400 bad request from time to time since April 16, 2021

Tags: sharepoint, csom

we are using CSOM to communicate with SharePoint Online.

Since April 16th, 2021 we recognize http 400 responses from different parts of our code using CSOM calls from time to time. We added status 400 to our internal retry logic. Executing the same call a few seconds later succeeds. So pretty much a wrong status code.

It seems like SharePoint should generate a 429 throttling response at that time and somehow generates an incorrect 400.

Does anybody else experience the same?

Regards
Sven

Comment: Wow, we currently investigate the exact same problem. I even got the HTTP 400 from [within PowerShell the other day](https://imgur.com/v76fV0c). We thought about logging the response body of the HTTP 400 packet in the hope to discover a more meaningful message. We are also close to re-implement the retry logic for 400 error codes too. We encounter those problems even before the 16th.

Comment: We tried to set the user agent as described in the msdn docs, parsed the response body and header of the message but discovered no meaningful hint why this error happens. In the request header is a correlation guid. It's sadly not possible to get the uls logs from sharepoint online. We are close to open a call but I am very busy right now...

Comment: In our case the response is just an html page with this message "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details". We log the http headers but nothing helpful in there as well.

Comment: Same for us. We found a correlation guid within the header though: host header field names ``SPRequestGuid'`` and ``request-id``. Can't investigate further as it appears that Microsoft doesn't allow to access log files.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has fixed the issue on May 7th as reported here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6955

We could not find any http 400 failures in our logs after 5/7, so the fix seems to work in our case.